# Pass returned list Erlang

Tags: case

I want to pass my returned list into case but I'm getting the

> "->" Error

Here is my code:

```
parse ( Element, [] ) -> false;
parse(Element,N) ->  re:split(N,"([*+])",[{return,list}]),


parse ( Element, [ Item | ListTail ] ) ->
case ( Item == Element ) of
    true    ->  true;
    false   ->  listFind(Element, ListTail)
end.
```

I don't know how to pass the returned list into the case, Can anyone help?

Comment: can you explain why down votes thx it would help

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking; do you mean "pass" or "parse"; what is "the -> Error" supposed to mean? Why are you attempting to pass the returned list into the case? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Oh, and your code is inconsistently formatted, which is probably why you've not noticed the (I assume) incorrect `,` at the end of the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the result of `re:split/3` in a `case`, you need to get rid of the extraneous function head stuck inside the second clause of `parse/2`. You also don't need the first clause of `parse/2`, as it's unnecessary and not used. Just look through the result of `re:split/3` for `Element`, like this:

```
parse(Element, N) ->
    Elements = re:split(N,"([*+])",[{return,list}]),
    lists:member(Element, Elements).
```

If for example the argument `N` has the value `"a*b+c*d+e"`, the `re:split/3` call returns `["a","*","b","+","c","*","d","+","e"]` (and let's assume that's really what you want). The call to `lists:member/2` then searches that result for the value of `Element`, returning `true` if found or `false` if not found.